# Inserting element into left leaning black red tree c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have been staring at this all day and have gotten slightly somewhere, but it's still not working correctly! Just trying to 'put' (really insert, or find if it's there) an element k into a LL red black tree. Here's my method:

```
Node * RPut(Node* p, const K& k, Node*& location)
{
  // if you are at the bottom of the tree,
  // add new node at bottom of the tree
  if (p == 0)
  {
    // new red note with new data
    location = NewNode(k, Data(), RED);
    return location;
  }

  if(greater_(k,p->key_))
  {
    // if it's greater than the root, move down to the left child
    p->left_ = Rput(p->left_, k, location);
  }
  // right subtree
  else if (greater_(p->key_,k))
  {
    // but if the key is less than root, move down to right child
    p->right_ = Rput(p->right_, k, location);
  }
  // if they are equal
  else
  {
    location = p;
  }   
  // code for rotating
  // this sort of worked.
  if(p->right_ && p->right_->IsRed())
  {
    p = RotateLeft(p);
    if (p->left_->IsBlack())
    {
      p->SetBlack();
      p->left_->SetRed();
    }
  }
  if (p->left_ && p->left_->IsRed())
  {       if (p->left_->left_ && p->left_->left_->IsRed())
    {
        p = RotateRight(p);
        p->left_->SetBlack();
        p->right_->SetBlack();
     }
   }
   return p;
}
```

I know my rotate methods work perfectly. This inserts correctly until the fifth element (I haven't tried every combination, but usually.) For instance, abcde inserted correctly would be

```
   d
  b  e
 a c --
```

[with b as red node]

mine works but stops here, giving me:

```
    b
  a   d
- -  c   e
```

with NO red nodes.

Anyone see anything obvious I am overlooking or why it isn't working properly? Any help at all much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This does not directly answer the question, but have you read Sedgewick's [paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf) on left-leaning red black trees? The code in it is exceptionally clear, there are beautiful diagrams explaining how things work, and, I imagine, it would be straight-forward to reimplement everything into C++.

[image: Sedgewick's Insert Function]

[image: Sedgewick's rotate function]

**Edit**

I tried, for fun to implement Sedgewick's code. It turns out the paper had a few methods/subroutines left out that would have been pretty helpful to include. Anyway, my C++11 implementation, along with some tests, follows.

Since Java does automagic memory management, Sedgewick doesn't explicitly note where memory should be freed in his code. Rather than try to figure this out for a quick project and possibly leave memory leaks, I've opted to use `std::shared_ptr`, which provides a similar worry-free behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

template<class keyt, class valuet>
class LLRB {
 private:
  static const bool COLOR_RED   = true;
  static const bool COLOR_BLACK = false;

  class Node {
   public:
    keyt   key;
    valuet val;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
    bool   color;
    Node(keyt key, valuet val){
      this->key   = key;
      this->val   = val;
      this->color = COLOR_RED;
      this->right = nullptr;
      this->left  = nullptr;
    }
  };

  typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> nptr;

  nptr root;

  nptr rotateLeft(nptr h){
    nptr x  = h->right;
    h->right = x->left;
    x->left  = h;
    x->color = h->color;
    h->color = COLOR_RED;
    return x;
  }

  nptr rotateRight(nptr h){
    nptr x  = h->left;
    h->left  = x->right;
    x->right = h;
    x->color = h->color;
    h->color = COLOR_RED;
    return x;
  }

  nptr moveRedLeft(nptr h){
    flipColors(h);
    if(isRed(h->right->left)){
      h->right = rotateRight(h->right);
      h        = rotateLeft(h);
      flipColors(h);
    }
    return h;
  }

  nptr moveRedRight(nptr h){
    flipColors(h);
    if(isRed(h->left->left)){
      h = rotateRight(h);
      flipColors(h);
    }
    return h;
  }

  void flipColors(nptr h){
    h->color        = !h->color;
    h->left->color  = !h->left->color;
    h->right->color = !h->right->color;
  }

  bool isRed(const nptr h) const {
    if(h==nullptr) return false;
    return h->color == COLOR_RED;
  }

  nptr fixUp(nptr h){
    if(isRed(h->right) && !isRed(h->left))       h = rotateLeft (h);
    if(isRed(h->left)  &&  isRed(h->left->left)) h = rotateRight(h);
    if(isRed(h->left)  &&  isRed(h->right))          flipColors (h);

    return h;
  }

  nptr insert(nptr h, keyt key, valuet val){
    if(h==nullptr)
      return std::make_shared<Node>(key,val);

    if     (key == h->key) h->val   = val;
    else if(key  < h->key) h->left  = insert(h->left, key,val);
    else                   h->right = insert(h->right,key,val);

    h = fixUp(h);

    return h;
  }

  //This routine probably likes memory
  nptr deleteMin(nptr h){
    if(h->left==nullptr) return nullptr;
    if(!isRed(h->left) && !isRed(h->left->left))
      h = moveRedLeft(h);
    h->left = deleteMin(h->left);
    return fixUp(h);
  }

  nptr minNode(nptr h){
    return (h->left == nullptr) ? h : minNode(h->left);
  }

  //This routine leaks memory like no other!! I've added a few cleanups
  nptr remove(nptr h, keyt key){
    if(key<h->key){
      if(!isRed(h->left) && !isRed(h->left->left))
        h = moveRedLeft(h);
      h->left = remove(h->left, key);
    } else {
      if(isRed(h->left))
        h = rotateRight(h);
      if(key==h->key && h->right==nullptr)
        return nullptr;
      if(!isRed(h->right) && !isRed(h->right->left))
        h = moveRedRight(h);
      if(key==h->key){
        std::shared_ptr<Node> mn = minNode(h->right);
        h->val = mn->val;
        h->key = mn->key;
        h->right = deleteMin(h->right);
      } else {
        h->right = remove(h->right, key);
      }
    }

    return fixUp(h);
  }

  void traverse(const nptr h) const {
    if(h==nullptr)
      return;
    traverse(h->left);
    std::cout<< h->key << "=" << h->val <<std::endl;
    traverse(h->right);
  }

 public:
  LLRB(){
    root = nullptr;
  }

  void traverse() const {
    traverse(root);
  }

  valuet search(keyt key){
    nptr x = root;
    while(x!=nullptr){
      if      (key == x->key) return x->val;
      else if (key  < x->key) x=x->left;
      else                    x=x->right;
    }

    return keyt();
  }

  void insert(keyt key, valuet val){
    root        = insert(root,key,val);
    root->color = COLOR_BLACK;
  }

  void remove(keyt key){
    root        = remove(root,key);
    root->color = COLOR_BLACK;
  }
};

int main(){
  for(int test=0;test<500;test++){
    LLRB<int,int> llrb;
    std::vector<int> keys;
    std::vector<int> vals;

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
      //Ensure each key is unique
      int newkey = rand();
      while(llrb.search(newkey)!=int())
        newkey = rand();

      keys.push_back(newkey);
      vals.push_back(rand()+1);
      llrb.insert(keys.back(),vals.back());
    }

    //llrb.traverse();

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
      if(llrb.search(keys[i])!=vals[i]){
        return -1;
      }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
      llrb.remove(keys[i]);

    for(int i=500;i<1000;i++){
      if(llrb.search(keys[i])!=vals[i]){
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout<<"Good"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I have not! I tried a variation similar to this though, and was having seg fault issues. Going to try again following his logic.

Comment: I wonder if you could find ways to put some sanity assertions in your code? The `assert()` function will blow things up if something goes wrong, can be left out of the compilation later for speed, and tells you what failed when a failure happens.

Comment: @Tracy *I tried a variation similar to this though, and was having seg fault issues* -- IMO the issue is that C++ is not a good (should say ideal) language to use if you want to implement a data structure according to what you read in textbooks.  A language like Java is more suited for this.  The reason is that for C++, you have to worry about properly managing dynamically allocated memory, unlike other languages.  So you have two mountains to climb -- the language itself and the data structure you're implementing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well that is good to know, I see a variation on this simple implementation everywhere and seems to work. I don't know. I just tried again, and I get a seg fault after entering a second variable into the list. It must be in one of the if's, because it falls past the comparison loop no problem and then seg faults without entering a loop.

Comment: @Richard have never used assert() but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tracy: I had a little spare time, so I implemented the LLRB following Sedgewick's paper. Perhaps you'll find it to be helpful. Like you, I had issues at around 5 objects. These arose due to not setting `h` to the return value of `fixUp()` in the insertion routine. Also had issues because the `left` and `right` pointers, and `root`, needed to be initialized.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: There's no need for proselytization here.

Comment: Wow.. awesome job Richard. That is a terrific reference.. never heard of a sharedptr before - I just looked it up. Wish I could use your logic for this project but unfortunately my nodes set up with these particular flags that I think possibly my issues are stemming from. Can I ask a very basic question- what happens when you call fixup on left and right pointers that are still 'nullptr'? It looks like it still operates completely fine, right? I set all mine to nullptr if they didn't exist but got seg faults everywhere.

Comment: I've also tried creating temp nodes in every combination possible (every flag, temp variables, 0's).. and still seg faults. There's something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes, you can run fixUp on null pointers because isRed protects against abuse.

Comment: Didn't even notice. I'm going to put a few null pointer checks in. Thanks!

Comment: I did. I simply had my the order of the statements in both my if statements wrong! I do not recall the correct order. But they were the issue.

Comment: @Tee: If you feel this answer adequately addressed your question you can accept it by clicking the outline of a checkmark next to it :-)